# netstat: See process name like in `ps aux`

Tags: ps, netstat

The postfix daemon has only the name "master" if I use `netsat` like this:

```
root@myhost# netstat -tulpen| grep master
tcp  0  0 127.0.0.1:25  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  0  53191445 13640/master
```

If I use `ps` I get a more verbose name:

```
root@myhost# ps aux| grep 13640
root     13640  0.0  0.0  25036  1500 11:35   0:00 /usr/lib/postfix/master
```

Is there a way to tell `netstat` to output the long name?

In this case it would be `/usr/lib/postfix/master`.

## Update

It seems that netstat can't do it. If you know how to do this with an other tool, then this is valid question, too. (But netstat based solutions are still prefered).

## Update2

All answers work. Thank you very much for showing your unix knowledge. But up to now the answers are far too long/complicated.

Is there no easy solution? I can install any tool which is needed, but I want the usage to be simple to use.

## I can't give the bounty to all of you ...

There are several answers which to post processing to get the needed information. Each answer uses a different way and I don't see that one solution is better than an other.

Unfortunately there seems to be no unix/linux which can do this out of the box. But that's not the fault of you, who tried to help me.

Unfortunately I can't give the bounty to all answers :-)

I gave the bounty to the user with the least reputation points.

Comment: Use `lsof` instead.

Comment: @SatoKatsura during the last years I mostly used netstat. Are there any other good reasons to switch? Up to now this question is the first feature I am missing.

Comment: Who said anything about _switching_.  `lsof` has lots of features.  On the other hand `netstat` is OS-dependent, and its features don't completely overlap with those of `lsof`.  You should use both when appropriate.

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible to see the full command line in netstat. I think it is reading the file /proc/13640/comm, and that is only showing the "master" name

Comment: If you use Linux, please not that `netstat` is deprecated in favor of `ss`. It has the same limitation as you point out, however.

Comment: Does simply piping to `full` [(as defined in my answer)](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/318031/135943) qualify as "easy to use"?  :)

Answer (score 6):

This is the most interesting search for an "elegant" solution I've had in some time.  Thank you.

## General comment:

Rather than parsing `/proc/pid/cmdline`, it makes much more sense to run `readlink /proc/pid/exe` instead.

## What it looks like:

I set up a shell function `full` to abstract the complexity out of this—mostly just to save on typing.

The only dependencies are [POSIX-compliant `ex`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html) and Linux standard `readlink`.

In the following terminal output I have piped through `head` for brevity.

```
[root@localhost ~]# netstat -tulpen | head
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       User       Inode      PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          9581       1237/sshd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          10164      1493/master         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:555                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          14326      2824/nc             
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:46638               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      29         8848       960/rpc.statd       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          8749       940/rpcbind         
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      0          9583       1237/sshd           
tcp        0      0 ::1:25                      :::*                        LISTEN      0          10166      1493/master         
tcp        0      0 :::47166                    :::*                        LISTEN      29         8856       960/rpc.statd       
[root@localhost ~]# netstat -tulpen | head | full
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       User       Inode      PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          9581       1237/usr/sbin/sshd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          10164      1493/usr/libexec/postfix/master         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:555                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          14326      2824/usr/bin/nc             
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:46638               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      29         8848       960/sbin/rpc.statd       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          8749       940/sbin/rpcbind         
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      0          9583       1237/usr/sbin/sshd           
tcp        0      0 ::1:25                      :::*                        LISTEN      0          10166      1493/usr/libexec/postfix/master         
tcp        0      0 :::47166                    :::*                        LISTEN      29         8856       960/sbin/rpc.statd       
[root@localhost ~]#
```

It also works with any form of `netstat -p`, even the forms that have other trailing data on some lines:

```
[root@localhost ~]# netstat -p | head
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:ssh               10.0.2.2:63550              ESTABLISHED 2557/sshd           
Active UNIX domain sockets (w/o servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node PID/Program name    Path
unix  11     [ ]         DGRAM                    8584   895/rsyslogd        /dev/log
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    9124   1045/hald           @/org/freedesktop/hal/udev_event
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    7116   340/udevd           @/org/kernel/udev/udevd
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    16523  3537/pickup         
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    15036  2865/su             
[root@localhost ~]# netstat -p | head | full
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:ssh               10.0.2.2:63550              ESTABLISHED 2557/usr/sbin/sshd           
Active UNIX domain sockets (w/o servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node PID/Program name    Path
unix  11     [ ]         DGRAM                    8584   895/sbin/rsyslogd        /dev/log
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    9124   1045/usr/sbin/hald           @/org/freedesktop/hal/udev_event
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    7116   340/sbin/udevd           @/org/kernel/udev/udevd
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    16523  3537/usr/libexec/postfix/pickup         
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    15036  2865/bin/su             
[root@localhost ~]#
```

## How it's defined:

```
[root@localhost ~]# type full
full is a function
full () 
{ 
    ex -c 'g/^.*\(\<[0-9]\+\)\/.*$/ya|pu|s::readlink /proc/\1/exe:|.!sh' -c 'g/^\//-ya|pu|-2s/^\(.*\<[0-9]\+\)\/[^[:space:]]*\(.*\)$/\1/|+2s//\2/|-2j!3' -c%p -c 'q!' /dev/stdin
}
[root@localhost ~]#
```

## How it works (step by step breakdown):

(Forthcoming; in the meantime try it out and let me know how you like it.)

Comment: holy regex wildness batman!

Comment: @javadba, no kidding.  If you'd like that "forthcoming" breakdown I can oblige, though.  :)

Answer (score 5):

As you already figured `netstat` by default cannot provide full `cmdline` output with `-p` option. As per source it seem to limited to [20 chars](https://github.com/ecki/net-tools/blob/master/netstat.c#L110) and only lists [portion of the full cmdline](https://github.com/ecki/net-tools/blob/master/netstat.c#L468)

You could write your own wrapper around netstat to display full details. Added below snippet of python code which displays full cmd line.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from subprocess import Popen,PIPE

out,err = Popen(['netstat','-antlp'],stdout=PIPE).communicate()

for l in out.splitlines():
    line = l.split()
    if '/' in line[-1]:
        p = line[-1].split('/')[0]
        line[-1] = str(p) + ' -> ' + open('/proc/'+p+'/cmdline','r').readline().split('-')[0]
    print '\t'.join(line)
```

Sample output:

```
$ sudo ./netstat.py 
Active  Internet    connections (servers    and established)
Proto   Recv-Q  Send-Q  Local   Address Foreign Address State   PID/Program name
tcp 0   0   0.0.0.0:11443   0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN  4007 -> /usr/sbin/apache2
tcp 0   0   192.168.2.125:53    0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN  3055 -> /usr/sbin/named
tcp 0   0   172.17.0.1:53   0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN  3055 -> /usr/sbin/named
tcp 0   0   192.168.125.1:53    0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN  3055 -> /usr/sbin/named
tcp 0   0   192.168.0.200:53    0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN  3055 -> /usr/sbin/named
tcp 0   0   127.0.0.1:53    0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN  3055 -> /usr/sbin/named
tcp 0   0   0.0.0.0:22  0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN  3125 -> /usr/sbin/sshd
tcp 0   0   127.0.0.1:631   0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN  30845 -> /usr/sbin/cupsd
tcp 0   0   127.0.0.1:25    0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN  3884 -> /usr/sbin/exim4
tcp 0   0   127.0.0.1:953   0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN  3055 -> /usr/sbin/named
tcp 0   0   0.0.0.0:32765   0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN  3014 -> /sbin/rpc.statd
tcp 0   0   0.0.0.0:8895    0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN  4078 -> /home/cv/jdk1.8.0_31/bin/java
tcp 0   0   0.0.0.0:23423   0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN  4078 -> /home/cv/jdk1.8.0_31/bin/java
tcp 0   0   0.0.0.0:32767   0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN  3827 -> /usr/sbin/rpc.mountd
tcp 0   0   0.0.0.0:23424   0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN  4078 -> /home/cv/jdk1.8.0_31/bin/java
tcp 0   0   0.0.0.0:32768   0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN  -
tcp 0   0   0.0.0.0:2049    0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN  -
tcp 0   0   0.0.0.0:23523   0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN  4078 -> /home/cv/jdk1.8.0_31/bin/java
tcp 0   0   0.0.0.0:23524   0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN  4078 -> /home/cv/jdk1.8.0_31/bin/java
tcp 0   0   192.168.0.200:44331 0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN  4078 -> /home/cv/jdk1.8.0_31/bin/java
tcp 0   0   0.0.0.0:111 0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN  3002 -> /sbin/rpcbind
tcp 0   0   0.0.0.0:8080    0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN  4007 -> /usr/sbin/apache2
tcp 0   0   0.0.0.0:6000    0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN  3908 -> /usr/bin/Xorg:0
```

You could write your own wrapper around similar lines and add to your toolbox!

Answer (score 3):

Just to have fun I made this:

```
sudo netstat -putan | awk '/master/ {out=""; for(i=1;i<=6;i++){out=out" "$i}; split($7,result,"/"); system("ps aux | grep -v grep | grep " result[1] " >> x&"); getline < "x"; print out " " $14}'
```

I think is what you want. You can always use it as an alias, to simplify its use.

**Explanation:**

The next line gets the output of netstat and it filters `master`

```
sudo netstat -putan | awk '/master/
```

The next line stores the output of netstat.

```
out=""; for(i=1;i<=6;i++){out=out" "$i}
```

The next line gets the pid:

```
split($7,result,"/")
```

The next line gets the full name from ps aux and it prints everything

```
system("ps aux | grep -v grep | grep " result[1] " >> x&"); getline < "x";
```

Finally it is printed:

```
print out " " $14
```

Comment: Having fun is important. "Just for fun" is the title of the book by Linus Torvalds :-). Thank you for this answer.

Comment: Simpler: `| awk '/master/ { split($7,result,"/); NF=6; save=$0; "ps hp" result[1] | getline; print save,$5 }'`

Comment: Agree with @dave_thompson_085; don't use `grep -v grep` in a script (only interactively).  Instead, actually learn and correctly use the flags to `ps` to get the *actual* results you want.

Comment: the python solutuon is more readable and more generic, versatile

Answer (score 2):

Use the Linux tool `lsof`. But it may not be installed on some Unix flavours.

```
lsof -i  tcp | grep -w "pid"
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar solution to @iñaki-murillo but using `/proc/pid/cmdline` instead of `ps` and `grep`. I also use `$NF` and assume the last field is in `pid/procname` format rather than assume that it is $7 (It was actually $6 on my system).

```
netstat -putan|awk '/master/ {split($NF, pid,"/");sub(FS $NF,x);getline cmd < ("/proc/"pid[1]"/cmdline");print $0" "pid[1]"/"cmd}'
```

**Explanation**

`/master/` Filter on lines containing master.

`split($NF, pid,"/");` Split the last field on `/` and store in `pid`

`sub(FS $NF,x);` Delete the last field.

`getline cmd < ("/proc/"pid[1]"/cmdline")` Read the command line call of the pid in question and save it in `cmd`.

`print $0" "pid[1]"/"cmd` Print it all out

Answer (score 0):

With `xargs` & `readlink`:

```
$ netstat -tulpen \
    | grep chrome \
    | xargs -L1 bash -c 'echo $@ $(readlink /proc/${7//[A-Z\/]/}/exe)'
0 0 0.0.0.0:5353 0.0.0.0:* 1000 17007 2521/chrome /opt/google/chrome/chrome
```