# Can you widen the columns in netstat, specifically "PID/Program name" ...?

Tags: netstat

There is an old post about line truncation in `netstat` ([Netstat output line width limit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212096/netstat-output-line-width-limit)) but my question is a bit different.

I'm using `netstat` (net-tools 2.10) on Debian 12. My primary use is to list listening ports, e.g. `netstat -tunlpWee` I find the `PID/Program name` column to been too narrow. Is there a way to widen this?

Option `-T` is unsupported. Option `-W` (`--wide`) does not help as this only affects IP addresses. Option `-e` is about "additional information," not "wider information."

At this point, I see my only option to be to wrap `netstat` in a script and leverage `ps` to get a broader "program name." Unless ... I'm missing something obvious.

UPDATE:
Thanks, davidt930. That's disappointing. I came up with this solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# show applications using ports
# use sudo to get the process name
# The "PID/Program name" as returned by netstat(8) is too narrow for my tastes.
# Therefore, I wrap netstat's output in a series of calls to ps(1) to get
# broader application details, i.e. the full command line.

PPWID=20
data=
while IFS= read -r ln ; do
  [ -z "$data" ] && {
    echo "$ln"
    [ "${ln/PID\/Program name/}" != "$ln" ] && data=Y || :
    continue
  } || :
  static="${ln:0:-$PPWID}"
  program="${ln:0-$PPWID}"
  [ "${program:0:1}" = "-" ] && command="(need privileges)" || {
    pid=${program%%/*}
    command=$(ps -o command -p $pid | tail -1)
  }
  echo "${static}${command}"
done< <(netstat -tunlpWee)
```

It's a tad fragile as it relies on `netstat` keeping the `PID/Program name` column fixed at 20.

Comment: Try `ss` instead: `ss -OHnltp`

Comment: Or `lsof`: `lsof -nP -i tcp -s tcp:LISTEN -Fcn`

Comment: Nice. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get the process name and its command line with `ss`

Comment: Unfortunately, `lsof -nP ..` (w/o `sudo`) shows nothing. With `sudo`, it outputs unusable data all crammed into one column.

Comment: with `-F` `lsof` outputs a parsable output with the first letter the type of data (pid, fd, command, name) followed by the value. Remove that `-Fcn` for a multicolumn output.

Comment: `ss -p` like `lsof` or `netstat -p` will report only your own sockets if you're not root.

Comment: Without `-Fcn` I do get multi-column output. However, I get only the command, not the command line.

Comment: See also `lsfd` if available on your machine for another one with parseable output.

Comment: Yes, I don't expect any of those would return the whole list of arguments passed to the last execve() the process did (I guess what you call the command line, and what `ps -f` represents with some transformation), that would make little sense for them to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `Program name` column's width is hard coded[0] in `netstat` to `20` characters. So it is not possible to widen it without modifying the source itself.

Like you, I use `ps` to get broader program name. Ways to list full program names are discussed here [1].

[0] https://sources.debian.org/src/net-tools/2.10-0.1/netstat.c/#L256

[1] [netstat: See process name like in `ps aux`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/315865/netstat-see-process-name-like-in-ps-aux)